# saned.service is DEAD! When trying to connect my scanner at my computer on WIFI

Tags: networking, wireless, services, systemd, scanner

On my Ubuntu 16.04 I checked the status of saned:

```
$ sudo service saned status
saned.service
Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I have done this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rolfbensch/sane-release
sudo apt-get update
```

And it's still not working!

What should I do?

Comment: why does your post have the tags [networking] and [wireless]? Have you installed the `sane` package? Why did you think you needed to add a PPA? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: II try to connect my scanner canon PIXMA 5750 at my computer over WIFI using router CONCEPTRONIC.

Comment: Well [edit] your question to say that instead of asking about something you think is related to your problem

Comment: I have edited my title! thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Canon scanner.

On SANE page it is listed as [Untested](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON) and supported by *sane-pixma* driver.

You can consult [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SANE/Scanner-specific_problems#Scanning_over_the_network_with_Canon_Pixma_all-in-one_printer.2Fscanners) for accessing it.

> **Scanning over the network with Canon Pixma all-in-one printer/scanners**
>
> Find out your printer/scanner's IP address, and add it on a new line to */etc/sane.d/pixma.conf* in the format `bjnp://10.0.0.20`.
>
> Sane should now find your device. For more details refer to `sane-pixma(5)`.
>
> Alternative: for some Canon Pixma all-in-one printer/scanners, which are not detected over network, can be used [scangearmp](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/scangearmp2/) package from AUR.

All you need is `libsane` package and [`man sane-pixma`](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-pixma.5.html). Not sure about scangearamp.

Comment: saned.service "masked" is a KNOWN BUG "saned.service masked and cannot be unmasked" BUG 1577137. That's exactly what happened to me. NO WAY to unmasked it, I try everything!